# how to filter files by extension in pantheon-files

Tags: pantheon-files

i want to know if its possible to filter by extension which files in a directory are shown. 
in many file managers you can add for example *.jpg to the path.
that did not work for me and the documentation is non existent.

Comment: just right click in the folder you want to be sorted and choose `Sort by -> Type` then automatically the files will be organized by extension in alphabetical order. you can also use the terminal for that, just `ls *.[extension]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment, although it is something that could be implemented in future.  The only work-round is to sort by type, as indicated above.

The intention is the elementaryos apps are simple enough to be self-documenting so if there is no obvious way of doing something it is probably not implemented!  Of course, at present, this ideal is not always reached ...